# Text in UISegmentedControl not exactly centered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

Maybe it's just me, but it seems like the bottom padding is greater than the top padding for the text in this `UISegmentedControl`. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Maybe looks that way because room is left for a descender, and there are no descenders because you've used all caps.

Comment: I think you're right..so to fix this would I have to manually move the text a couple pixels down?

Comment: Sure, just shove it down with the content offset: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl-SW23

Comment: Or call `setContentPositionAdjustment:forSegmentType:barMetrics:`

Comment: @matt Adjusting the content offset worked! Feel free to add as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is probably correct, but it looks wrong to your eye because room is left for a descender, and there are no descenders because the titles are all caps. Luckily, you can adjust the `y`-component of the content position! There are two ways:

- In Interface Builder, in the attributes inspector for each segment, set the Content Offset
- In code, call `setContentPositionAdjustment:forSegmentType:barMetrics:`