# Vertical content offset for uisegmentcontrol

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add an offset for uisegmentcontrol:

[image]

In this image, I would like to vertically lower the strings of "Name", "Date", and "Company" to vertical center.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text in UISegmentedControl not exactly centered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617801/text-in-uisegmentedcontrol-not-exactly-centered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative number moves the text up, positive moves the text down.

```
[self.mySegment setContentOffset:CGSizeMake( 0, -5 ) forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

You can get more information from Apple's [UISegmentedControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).